# Core data enabled Project not loading 'CoreData'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a new project which has core data enabled in swift. But when I load the project there is an error message in the app-delegate file saying

"cannot load module 'Coredata' as 'CoreData' ". I have attached a screenshot of my [image: appdelegate.swift] for easy understandability of the error.

I checked doing core data in objective c and its working fine but why is it having problems in Swift?

I have tried out all possible means. I have deleted the whole project and did a new one but still the problem persists. I don't know what to do. Any project in swift in which I enable coredata has the same problem. I also reinstalled the XCode and replaced the old ome by a new one but the problem is still there.

Comment: Does "Coredata" with that exact capitalization exist anywhere in your project?

Comment: @PhillipMills I can't get you.

Comment: @PhillipMills Please help. It is not the case of a single project. Any swift project I am creating enabling CoreData it shows the same problem everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the error message it states that there seems to to be a module called "Coredata" (with the 5th letter not capitalized). This implies, as Phil points out, that somewhere in your project you have a reference to a module that has exactly this strange spelling.

Best try to create a project and *not* call it "Coredata" but something more distinct, such as "CDTest" or so.

Also you should first try to make it work in pure Swift without using and Objective-C. I recommend rewriting the `Student` classes in Swift anyway.

If you insist on mixing Objective-C and Swift, I would guess the error is in your bridging header. Perhaps you did not follow the right procedure when adding your Objective-C files.

Comment: I have tried out all possible means. I have deleted the whole project and did a new one but still the problem persists. I don't know what to do. Any project in swift in which I enable coredata has the same problem. I also reinstalled the XCode and replaced the old ome by a new one but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that there was some old file which was named as Coredata which was present deep inside the cache of XCode and I needed to clear that. So I went through the cache cleaning process mentioned in the question- [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#)

Answer (score 0):

appdelicate.swift is the part of coredata so there is no need to import it again...

[image: screen shots]